# Page not found , android webView

Tags: android, webview

This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        /*webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
         });*/

        webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");

    }

...
...
...
```

I set the Internet permission on the manifest.
If I uncomment the setWebViewClient the result it's the same.

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: try `https://www.google.com`

Comment: And have you really connected Internet? Check once.

Comment: AabraKaDabra is happening then :-)

Comment: I solved only with the Https. thanks manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView does not assume you want to use HTTP by default. When parsing URLs with WebView, you need to always identify the protocol you wish to use to retrieve the resource.

So instead of just specifying `www.google.com` load the website with:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```